# how can i update my postmeta without losing old data?

Tags: php, meta-value

I have a code that stores old and new meta_value in the same meta_key but i don't know if it's right or wrong (note that i want to store data in the same meta_key not separate meta_key):

```
<?php
global $post;
$get_my_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', true );
$post_meta_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name-en',true);
$meta = array(
'name'          => $post_meta_name,
'chap'          => $season['quality_serie']
);
$updatemeta = array ($get_my_meta, $meta);
if($get_my_meta){ update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', $updatemeta );
} else { add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', $meta, true );
} ?>
```

when i want to get and show the stored data, it shows only the last data not all the data:

```
<?php
$first_link = get_post_meta($post->ID,"my_meta", true);
if($first_link){
    ?>
<?php
foreach( $first_link as $season){
?>
<ul>
   <li>
    <?php echo $season['chap'];?>
    <?php echo $season['name'];?>
   </li>
</ul>
<?php }} ?>
```

can any one modify this code?

Comment: Instead of `update_post_meta` use `add_post_meta`, problem solved =]. also `get_post_meta($post->ID,"my_meta", true)`, the third argument `true`, will return the first result, change it to `false` or completely omit it

Comment: with doing this: with true, it only store one data and without true, it store in separate meta_key

Comment: I know, I'm talking about `update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', $updatemeta )`, this function will update that meta with new values instead of adding to it, change this to `add_post_meta`

Comment: exactly. i did this. changing `update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', $updatemeta )` to `add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', $updatemeta, true )` and `add_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_meta', $updatemeta )` . but it only store one data or it store in separate meta_key

Comment: mention that my first code (that stores data) works fine but i can't get and show the stored data (it shows only the last data not all the stored data)

Comment: In that case instead of `get_post_meta($post->ID,"my_meta", true)` do `get_post_meta($post->ID,"my_meta")`

Comment: I did it but doesn't show any data

Answer (score 0):

The saving logic should be like this

```php
<?php
global $post;

$get_my_meta    = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta', true);
$post_meta_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name-en',true);

$meta = [
    'name' => $post_meta_name,
    'chap' => $season['quality_serie']
];

$updatemeta = [
    $get_my_meta,
    $meta
];

add_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta', $meta, true);
?>
```

And the loop logic should be like this

```php
<?php
$first_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_meta');

if ($first_link) : foreach( $first_link as $season) : 
?>
<ul>
   <li>
    <?php echo $season['chap'];?>
    <?php echo $season['name'];?>
   </li>
</ul>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

From your code I think that would work. If it doesn't, could you add a `print_r($first_link)` so I could replicate this in my local env for more testing?

Comment: this code only save one post_meta

Comment: this what `print_r($first_link)` returns from my first code: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => name4 [chap] => chap4 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name5 [chap] => chap5 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name6 [chap] => chap6 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name7 [chap] => chap7 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name8 [chap] => chap8 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name9 [chap] => chap9 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name10 [chap] => chap10 ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => name11 [chap] => chap11 ) )

Comment: @saeed Yeah.. thats not right. Ill do some testing and update my answer